# Mod rewrite and redirect not works

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Have redirect issue. I want to make rewrite extension from php to html all of my url's so i add this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Works amaizing, i can view page when i go to example: /index.html
But its not good for SEO because when i can visit page also from index.php ... 
How to make good redirect? When i try redirect using this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^index\.html  /index\.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

It's not working not redirect... Where I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional rewriterule to internally redirect **/index.html** to **/index.php** try :

```
##1)redirect /index.php to /index.html##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [L,R,NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [NC,L,R]
##2)internally redirect /index.html to /index.php##
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index\.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a redirect but serve php as html like this:

```
# Process PHP within .html  
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

(You have to rename your file.php into file.html)